# Integrating Speech Recognition into a Tkinter Todo List - Getting Audio but Not Updating Text Box

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on a voice-controlled to-do list application for a project using Tkinter and the SpeechRecognition library in Python. My goal is to capture voice commands and update a Tkinter Text widget with the recognized text. However, I'm facing an issue where I can successfully capture audio but struggle to get the widget to pop up.

```
import time
import keyboard
import speech_recognition as sr
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox


class TodoItem:
    def __init__(self, title):
        self.title = title
        self.completed = False


class TodoList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def add_item(self, text):
        item = TodoItem(text)
        self.items.append(item)
        print(f"Added {text}")

    def list_items(self):
        length = len(self.items)
        if length == 0:
            return "Your todo list is empty!"
        else:
            result = "Todo Items:\n"
            for i, item in enumerate(self.items):
                result += f"{i+1}. {item.title}\n"
            return result

    def remove_item(self, index):
        if 1 <= index <= len(self.items):
            item = self.items.pop(index - 1)
            print(f"Removed {item.title}")
            return f"Removed {item.title} from the todo list"
        else:
            return "Invalid index"


def get_text():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening for voice activation...")
        audio = r.listen(source)
        try:
            return r.recognize_google(audio).lower()
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            return ""


class TodoApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title("Todo List")
        self.geometry("400x300")

        self.todo = TodoList()

        self.label = tk.Label(
            self, text="Voice-controlled Todo List", font=("Helvetica", 16)
        )
        self.label.pack(pady=10)

        self.text_box = tk.Text(self, height=10, width=40)
        self.text_box.pack(pady=10)

        self.list_button = tk.Button(self, text="List Items", command=self.list_items)
        self.list_button.pack(pady=5)

        self.quit_button = tk.Button(self, text="Quit", command=self.quit_app)
        self.quit_button.pack(pady=5)

        # Start listening for voice input
        self.listen_for_activation()

    def listen_for_activation(self):
        spoken_text = get_text()
        # Display the recognized voice command in the text box
        self.text_box.delete("1.0", "end")
        self.text_box.insert("1.0", f"Voice Command: {spoken_text}")

        # Schedule the next call to listen_for_activation after 100 milliseconds
        self.after(100, self.listen_for_activation)

    def add_item_from_voice(self):
        text = self.text_box.get("1.0", "end-1c").strip()
        if text:
            self.todo.add_item(text)
            messagebox.showinfo("Success", f"Added {text} to the todo list")
            self.text_box.delete("1.0", "end")

    def remove_item_from_voice(self):
        index_text = self.get_spoken_index()
        try:
            index = int(index_text)
            result = self.todo.remove_item(index)
            messagebox.showinfo("Success", result)
        except ValueError:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Invalid input. Please enter a valid index.")

    def get_spoken_index(self):
        # Prompt the user to speak the index
        print("Please speak the index of the item you want to remove.")
        spoken_index = get_text()
        return spoken_index

    def list_items(self):
        result = self.todo.list_items()
        messagebox.showinfo("Todo List", result)

    def quit_app(self):
        self.destroy()


def main():
    app = TodoApp()
    app.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

In the listen_for_activation method, I'm successfully capturing audio with SpeechRecognition, but the Tkinter Text widget is not updating as expected. I want the Text widget to display the recognized text in real time.

I've attempted to use the text_box.insert() method to update the Text widget, but it doesn't seem to work as intended. How can I modify my code to achieve this?

Comment: If I modify `get_text()` to return a random word, I can see the word in the text box.